# Exit a loop by pressing a tk button

Tags: tcl

I'm new tcl/tk user. I just want a simple example of how can I exit a `foreach` loop by pressing a button. I tried to follow some examples from http://wiki.tcl.tk/564 but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Please show us what you're doing that doesn't work.  Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In order to interrupt a loop (which can be a `foreach` loop or any other kind), you have to run the event loop interlaced with the loop. This is done by calling `update` within the loop. Once the `update` finishes, you can then check a status variable to see if a termination has been requested.

```
set var 0
pack [button .b -text "Stop" -command {set var 1}]
foreach value $veryLongList {
    processThe $value
    update
    if {$var} {
        break
    }
}
destroy .b
```

## *BE AWARE!*

This makes the code potentially have reentrancy issues.

Comment: Great Donal is workink perfetly, what was what I looking for... Thanks!